# How can I extract the thick line in this isometric view

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, straight-line-detection

I have a 2d drawing of a element (isometric view) as follow:

[image]

I would like to extract only the thick, longest black line (element with arrows embedded in it not dimensions) from it.

How to achieve that ?

For now my code goes as follow

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

inputImage = cv2.imread("iso.jpg")
inputImageGray = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv2.Canny(inputImageGray, 150, 200, apertureSize=3)
minLineLength = 30
maxLineGap = 5

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
    image=edges,
    rho=cv2.HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC,
    theta=np.pi / 180,
    threshold=30,
    minLineLength=minLineLength,
    maxLineGap=maxLineGap,
)

for x in range(0, len(lines)):
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[x]:
        pts = np.array([[x1, y1], [x2, y2]], np.int32)
        cv2.polylines(inputImage, [pts], True, (0, 255, 0))

cv2.imshow("Result", inputImage)
cv2.imshow("Edges", edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Which gives fallowing result - it detect all lines also thin ones, text brackets etc.

[image]

Comment: Did you already try to remove thin lines using  [cv2.erode()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html)?

Comment: Please clarify "extract".  Do you want that removed or do you want only those black lines.  Get contours or canny edges and find only the horizontal ones.

Comment: I see 4 thick black lines - which one of them do you mean?

Comment: Morphology Erode the thin lines leaving the thick ones as suggested by Markus above.

Comment: @Markus - Will try with erosion - good idea.
MarkSetchell - the longest one with arrows embedded

Comment: @fmw42 pardon the title, that was my doing. I believe I improved it, perhaps not sufficiently. I'd guess that a mask would be a good start.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz - can you elaborate a bit about mask approach in this particular example ?

Comment: "mask" isn't an approach, it's a specific form of result. it says "yes/no" for each pixel. it says nothing about how that was determined.

Comment: Use morphology close rather than erode to remove the thin lines. Make the filter larger than the thin line thickness and smaller than the thick line thickness.

Comment: If you already `detect all lines`, why don't evaluate thickness of them?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I posted this under a misunderstanding. This is not what the OP wanted. The post was not clear. He apparently wants the medium thick lines with the arrows (from his subsequent comment).

Nevertheless, perhaps this will help someone else on a different project. So here is one way to get the thickest black lines using Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to grayscale
- Apply morphology close such that the kernel is thicker than the thin lines and thinner than the thick lines
- Threshold
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('schematic.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# apply morphology close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (3,3))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# threshold
result = cv2.threshold(gray, 32, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# save results
cv2.imwrite('schematic_thick_lines.jpg', result)

# show result
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Results:

[image]

You can use contours to extract each one separately if that is needed.

Comment: Fred, I think you understood the question same as me, but OP doesn't mean the thick horizontal lines you and I see, but actually the medium line with arrows on it.

Comment: Mark, why do you think that. He said clearly the thick black lines.

Comment: OP's comment from 11 hours ago... *"the longest one with arrows embedded"* That's exactly why I asked for clarification in my earlier comment.

Comment: I did not see that comment. Sorry.

Comment: It's fine. I like your answer.